# How to model user-configurable schemas in ElasticSearch 6+ ?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I work at a small SaaS startup.

As a SaaS software, you create an account and invite others.

We have some entities, like "product", but you can configure product's field.

Let's say you work with cars, you can create fields like "Model", "Year", "Weight", etc.

Let's say you work with clothes, you can create fields like "Size", "Gender", etc.

We have this modeled by SQL, but I want to have a replica in ElasticSearch for general searches and especially for customizeable reports.

To model this, I was considering the options:

1. One Index per Account Entity

   When an account is created, I'd create an index named something like "product-" and it would have its own schema.

   When the account's admin creates or changes an field, I'd need to use Update By Query or Reindex API.. idk.

   When an account is deleted, I'd need to delete the indexes.

   PRO: each index has an solid schema.

   CONS: creating/deleting indexes dynamically sounds scary.
2. One Index per Entity.

   This one seems ok too. I'd put "account_id" on every document, and filter it everytime.

   Would have only one index per entity: "products", "users", "contacts", "sales" etc.

   PRO: way simpler

   CONS: each index has multiples schemas. One per account_id

   I'm not sure how to consider the relationships either... Can I create relationships dynamically?

3. One Index to rule them all.

   One index "entities", with fields "account_id", "entity_type".

   Maybe I need to do this to map the relationships propertly. I'm quite confused. I did not understood fully the join field.

Anything that I'm missing?

Thanks for reading until here :)

Comment: Depends, if you do a lot of join queries in SQL it will not translate well to Elasticsearch. You may want to read through this first. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html

Comment: Maybe this is not a ElasticSearch use case..  Maybe use something like a graph database.

Comment: I think we are diverging here. My point was if you want to use multiple indices you need to consider the performance constraints you might face. On the other hand you can use a single index with dynamic mapping but in that case your queries would probably get complicated ( I am assuming from the info you have given ) and the dev effort along with it. In the end you and the team will have to decide what suits your need/use case best.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wanted to know if there is any design patterns to model this. Or even if create and delete indexes dynamically is a anti-pattern. Seems liks impossible to know before building a prove of concept. I will try some things then write a conclusion